# ADB: "failed to connect to '192.168.x.x:5555': Connection refused" tried both USB and Wifi

Tags: android, adb

On my `pixel3a` phone running `Android Pie`, I tried to adb connect to the phone using my macbook pro and it gave me a connection refused error

> "failed to connect to '192.168.xx.xxx:5555': Connection refused".

My macbook can adb connect to my other Android Pie and Oreo devices, therefore, I think the problem might be on the pixel3a phone side.

I'm guessing the debugging services is not running or somehow blocked on pixel3a which is why I keep getting connection refused.

NOTE: developer mode has been turned on and debugging over USB option has been turned on as well.

Anyone ran into similar issue? Thanks.

Btw, I tried to:

1. restart macbook and pixel3a.
2. connect through USB and Wifi.
3. look through to see if there is any app with the open port 5555 on the phone but none found.
4. see if there is anything open that looks like an adb debug using other ports than 5555 but don't see anything that looks like it.
5. turn off the developer/debugging mode then turn it back on again but still not working

p.s. I just got the phone and enabling the developer mode was the first thing I did.  I did not install any firewall or other apps besides the network monitor apps after I see the connection refuse error.

Comment: Just as a note: You don't have to hide `192.168.x.x` addresses. That's a private address space, so you can give it out all you want. It's only available from your own machine. You probably have 10 WIFI hotspots visible to you right now, and every one of them is using a 192.168 address space that would match yours.

Comment: have you enabled adb over network in you developer settings?

Comment: Hello Calvin,
Have you fixed this?

Answer (score 2):

This happens after a long period of inactivity. You need to restart the tcpip connection on port 5555.
Connect the phone to the computer via USB. Then in terminal navigate to platform-tools and insert the command...

> ./adb usb

expect the response  `restarting in USB mode`
Then ..

> ./adb tcpip 5555

and expect the response `restarting in TCP mode port: 5555`
You can now check your device ip address and add it..

> ./adb connect 192.168.86.40:5555

ps. If you added the path to bashrc, no need to go to the platform-tools folder, just replace the `./adb` with `adb` .